# Whats the problem with my code? I'm supposed to make a program that can tell you when an event finishes

Tags: python

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
minresult = ((mins + dura) % 60)
hourresult = (((60// dura) + hour) % 24)

print("The event will end on", hourresult,":" ,minresult)
```

If the inputs are 23, 58, and 642 the expected result is 10:40, but my program prints 23:40

Comment: To convert duration in minutes to duration in hours you need to divide by 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - you need to add mins to the hourresult calculation, and invert the division.

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
minresult = ((mins + dura) % 60)
hourresult = (((mins + dura)//60 + hour) % 24)

print("The event will end on", hourresult,":" ,minresult)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using %%time if you are using Jupyter Notebook.It would save a lot of time. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem in your code is that in 5th line it should be `dura// 60` instead of `60// dura`.

Also in the test case you have taken 23 as an input for hours, so the expected result should be 9 hours instead of 10 hours. It is so because it is taking into consideration 24th hour as well. Your 642 mins come out to be 10 hours 42 mins and hence, 23 + 1 hour = 24 hours, i.e., 1 day complete and 9 hours are left. The rest 9 hours are added on to another day and the output becomes 9.

And you are thinking that the minutes actually make 1 hour that is 24th hour and so it should display 10 as an output. So, for that, you have calculated hours and mins separately and hence those mins which actually make one complete hour doesen't show up in the output.

So, to get the proper output you will have to replace 5th line with

```
hourresult = ((int((mins + dura)/60) + hour) % 24)
```

As `int((mins + dura)/60)` will take the integer part of the total time the meeting will last in mins which are converted to hours by the division of 60.